# Submit button not working in IE/Safari, works in Chrome and information gets passed

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have sort of an odd problem that has been puzzling me. I have a content management system that is self made, and for a majority of the CRUD operations happen by checking to see what fields exist in the database, outputting it in a user friendly manner for editing of content, then submitting that content back into the database. These operations work perfectly in Chrome, however in Internet Explorer and Safari whenever I hit the submit button the page just seems to refresh without processing any information.

```
function createInsertForm($table, $formDesc, $carry, $carryUrl, $ext='', $formAppend='')
{
    // init globals
    global $cmsdir;
    global $pluginsdir;
    // put it together
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $pluginsdir . 'ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="' . $pluginsdir . 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>';
    echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" '.$formAppend.'>';
    createForm($table, 'insert', $formDesc);
    createFormButtons('yes', 'yes');
    if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit') {
        insertIntoDb($table, $carry, $carryUrl, $ext);
    }
    echo '</form>';
}

function createFormButtons($submit, $reset)
{
    echo '<div class="form-actions-min">';
    if ($submit == 'yes') {
        echo '<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">';
    }
    if ($reset == 'yes') {
        echo '<input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-warning btn-space">';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

page output example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../neou_cms/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../neou_cms/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <form action="/neou_cms/external_forms/testimonial.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" >
        <div class="form-desc"></div>
        <h3>Input Fields</h3>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="input-xlarge" id="tag_name" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Position</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="position" value="" class="input-xlarge" id="tag_position" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="company" value="" class="input-xlarge" id="tag_company" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Content Fields</h3>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Quote</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea name="quote" id="quote" rows="8" style="width:305px;"> </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="175013988" />
        <div class="form-actions-min"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-warning btn-space">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I wish I could be more specific and offer a better overview, but that would take ages! Does anyone have experience with an issue such as this, or perhaps know from my brief code what might be going wrong?

Comment: " seems to refresh" when i see language like that i wonder if you have done any basic debugging steps so that you KNOW where the issue is. `print_r($_POST);exit();` on testimonial.php, would be a good start

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit of a novice question, but if it isnt outputting any information to the database wouldn't that also be the same case for chrome?

Comment: In any case I get Array ( [name] => asd [position] => asd [company] => asd [quote] => asd [id] => 195301260 [submit] => Submit Query ) this information is getting processed but not put in the db. For example I have it setup so that I get a message that states whether or not information has been added, and in chrome i get that message, however, in ie, I just get the above (w no message)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you don't specify a `value` for your `<input type="submit">` button.  Since you don't specify a value the user-agent is free to use whatever value they chose as their default label.  In Chrome, it's "Submit".  In IE and Safari it's "Submit Query".

The way to avoid this problem is to add a `value` attribute to your `input` element:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: wow... i cannot believe i forgot that. fixed. thank you! had a feeling it was something so simple